# Porting netbeans java lay-out to android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, netbeans

I have been having some troubles with switching to android studio from Netbeans IDE to Android Studio. I have a few old projects. But I am getting stuck to one of my test projects so far.

I imported my .jar as a library into libs. My .jar includes a user interface but just not for android. Can I use this interface for android as well? Or otherwise what is the best way to XML port it. I have been TeamViewing with a friend, he said just mess around.

[jar to lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCgxv.png)

Steps I have done so far: (I hade some issues)

1. Add .jar as a lib
2. Edit build.gradle
3. Just mess around with the xml for a bit nothing really done there.

build.gradle looks like this.

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "nu.joeridamian.veganwords_anagram"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile files('libs/anagrams.jar')
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/anagrams.jar')
}
```

Now, of course, my biggest question now is it possible from here to just skip the whole android xml step and just use my .jar? If not what is the best way to use xml?

Test project I am working from: https://github.com/gekkevliegtuig/Veganwords-Anagram

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use this interface for android as well?
>    is it possible from here to just skip the whole android xml step and just use my .jar?

No. Android native layouts have to written the Android way.

> Or otherwise what is the best way to XML port it.

People have done crazier port-from-x-to-y before, but as far as I know, there isn't. You'll just have to write the UI part again.

> If not what is the best way to use xml?

Start by reading the official documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/overview.html